# Receiving Camel Twitter Consumer Endpoint Data

Tags: java, twitter, apache-camel

I have created a Route that looks roughly like this:

```
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("direct:twitter")

            .from("twitter://timeline/user?type=direct&user=" + this.uri)

            .choice()

                .when(body().isInstanceOf(Status.class))

                    .process(new MyTwitterProcessor())
                    .convertBodyTo(MyClass.class)
                    .to("log:do something")

            .endChoice()

        .to("log:mi amigo");

        }
```

Calling this route directly from producerTemplate.requestBody("direct:twitter", object), I expected to receive a list of MyClass.class instances. Instead, it is returning the object I sent in the requestBody method call.

Based on log statements "log:do something" I can see that Status objects are being returned- the request and response from twitter are clearly occuring.

I would like to understand why my route configuration is returning the object I send it, rather than the Status object results from twitter. I have written two other routes for Facebook posts and an RSS feed. They follow a similar pattern and return the response objects, rather than the request I sent.

I would also like to know what I can do to change the behavior so that producerTemplate.requestBody(...) returns a list of twitter messages.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [pollEnrich](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html) component to obtain additional data:

```
from("direct:twitter")
    .pollEnrich("twitter://timeline/user?type=direct&user=" + this.uri)
    .choice()
    ...
```

Alternatively, you may just use following route that is automatically started:

```
from("twitter://timeline/user?type=direct&user=" + this.uri)
    .choice()
    ...
```

Note, that the [twitter component](http://camel.apache.org/twitter.html) creates one route exchange per returned object and not a list.

Comment: Thank you, pollEnrich solved the problem I was having.